# How do I compile and run a program with multiple files/classes (Mac)?

Tags: java, compilation

I am trying to compile and run a program on my Mac, but the program has multiple classes.
I usually use Terminal (Mac equivalent of Windows Console) to compile and run my programs.

The steps I take are:

`cd TheDirectoryTheProgramIsIn` (directory)

`javac filename.java`           (compile)

`java filename`                 (run)

So what I know already is that each class has to be in separate files.
I was also informed of something called a package, and I don't know what that is. Maybe that is relevant.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I figured it out myself! What I did was compile the files without the main method first, then compiled the file with the main method. When I ran the file with the main method, it worked perfectly.

Comment: You may want to spend more time on teaching materials. This is pretty basic stuff so it is most likely covered in what you already have.